# Index Error: list index out of range using filepath

Tags: python, audio, mp3

I have this script that tries to find Style + Year on Discogs and writes it to the mp3 file.
It used to work before.
But now I get this error:
`Index Error: list index out of range`

I've de-installed 3.7.2, and re-installed 3.6.3 since I have chat logs where it shows it's working back then on that version.

When I set sys.argument to 0, no error, but no execution either.

```
for mp3file in Path(sys.argv[1]).glob('**/*.mp3'):
    print (mp3file)
    artist, title = return_tag_data(mp3file)
    artist_c = clean(artist)
    title_c = clean(title)
    style = get_style(artist_c, title_c, artist, title)
    year = get_year(artist_c, title_c, artist, title)
    if style != None:
        print ("Artist : {}\nTitle : {}\nStyle : {}\nYear : {}\n".format(artist, title, style, year))
        write_tag_data(mp3file, style, year)
```

It should show this:

```
c:\users\useraccount\music\My Music Collection\2-Step & Garage\187 Lockdown - Gunman (God Remix).mp3
Artist : 187 Lockdown
Title : Gunman (God Remix)
Style : Drum n Bass, Speed Garage
Year : 1997
```

But instead it throws this:

```
E:\test-mp3>python styleyear-mp3.py "e:\test-mp3"
e:\test-mp3\187 Lockdown - Gunman (GOD remix).mp3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "styleyear-mp3.py", line 111, in <module>
    style = get_style(artist_c, title_c, artist, title)
  File "styleyear-mp3.py", line 50, in get_style
    new_artist = y('spanitemprop title="(.+?)"')[0].strip()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: If you have the file, post the code corresponding to styleyear-mp3.py.

Comment: code here: https://pastebin.com/fxBKBWV1

Comment: insert if(len(x)>0): condition on line after x and y assignment. Similarly perform a check for y. You'll be golden